# installing ia32-libs package

Tags: android, linux, adb

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10, where I need to work with Android ADT bundle. When I try to open the log cat of ADT it was showing the following error

```
Cannot run program "xxx/sdk/platform-tools/adb": error=2,
```

Somehow I found the installing ia32-libs package will solve the issue. 
When I was trying to install the ia32-libs package on Ubuntu 12.10 I was getting following error message:

```
g500@G500:~$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch
 virtualbox-4.3 : Depends: libqt4-opengl (>= 4:4.7.2) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.10-1) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libvpx1 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: dkms but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Also I have tried the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386
```

but didn't get the expected result. 
Can someone help me regarding this issues on how to install ia32-libs package on Ubuntu 12.10 OS properly, so that I can run android adb.

Answer (score 0):

firstly replace ubuntu 12.10 source list with ubuntu 12.04 list , because ubuntu 12.10 support is ended , you cant get repo for this ..

you will get ubuntu 12.04 sourcelist from https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/sample/sources.list
copy the content and replace in /etc/apt/source.list ...
make sure for backup of this file

after that run update .. then try to install..this is must step

If it fails .. then simply install 32 bit java as i think this will be supportable for adt

sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk:i386

thanks

Comment: is there any command to see the current version of the OS installed?

Comment: $cat /etc/issue will show the os and version
for view the architecture $uname -m